# Angular 7, how to transpile imported modules to es5 for IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web3js

I have Angular 7 project with Web3js for ethereum. Unfortunately after build IE11 shows error `identifier expected`.

I am using angular cli 7.3.9 angular 7.

What is the correct way to transpile imported modules, from `node_modules` like Web3js?

```
const { keccak256, keccak256s } = __webpack_require__(/*! ./hash */ "./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/node_modules/eth-lib/lib/hash.js") <= identifier expected
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about the 'identifier expected' error? Maybe more stacktrace details?

Comment: I had a the same error msg recently when IE stumbled over `{...xxx}`  destructuring, but in an transient dependency (my code was correclty transpiled, but the code the code used was not). I had to change 1 dependency, and preload a vue plugin with babel-loader. I'm not sure how it works on angular, but I would start by identifing which code/lib the syntax error is occuring from.

Comment: exactly what I want to do, but I have no idea how force angular-cli to use babel-loader on imported modules, and add descructors. I have problem with vendors: const { keccak256, keccak256s } = __webpack_require__(/*! ./hash */ "./node_modules/ ... <= identifier expected